# Praying beginning or end has different reward?

Tags: salat

When someone prays in the beginning of the time is the reward different than the middle or end of time?

For example, if dhuhr prayer is at 11:30 and asr prayer is at 3:00. I prayed dhuhr at 2:45, do I get the same reward as the one that prayed it in the beginning of dhuhr prayer time?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you offer it at the recommended and acceptable times, it is rewarding.